# Windows batch & java: Combining -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError command and batch parameters

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, parameters

I am completely new to Windows batch programming.
What I want to achieve is to write a startup script for a Java application. Yet, it does not start the Java application, but rather prints out

> Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>
> (to execute a class)
>
> or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>
> (to execute a jar file)
>
> ...

which indicates that my parameters are not correctly recognized.

---

Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the not-working script:

```
set memory=600000
java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="taskkill /PID %p" -Xmx%memory%K -jar MyApp.jar
```

In the real scenario, `memory` is calculated to set the optimal maximal heap size for the application.

---

Leaving out one of both parameters makes the app start. So

```
java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="taskkill /PID %p" -jar MyApp.jar
```

and

```
set memory=600000
java -Xmx%memory%K -jar MyApp.jar
```

works, but I need both parameters to work in one call.

Comment: Try putting `@echo on`/`@echo off` in your script ([described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10237457/3788176)) and see what command it is actually executing in the "both parameters" case.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Using `@echo on` results in printing `java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="taskkill /PID memoryK -jar MyApp.jar`, which indicates some mistake with the `"`, which is not closed anymore, and the parameter, which is not added (`%memory%)`...

Comment: What it looks like is happening there is the `%` in `%p` is considered an "opening" `%` for substitution - I think that `%%` is the token for a single `%` (like in `printf`-like methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `@echo on` and `@echo off` in your script you can see what command is actually being executed.

You say that the resulting command is:

```
java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="taskkill /PID memoryK -jar MyApp.jar
```

which makes it look like the `%` of `%p` is being considered an "opening" `%` for the substitution.

Aside from the quotes not being balanced, this means that you are effectively not giving `java` a command to run - the `-jar MyApp.jar` is actually inside the `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` string.

Try replacing the single `%` with `%%` - according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551829/escape-percent-in-bat-file), that is how to write a literal `%` in a BAT file:

```
java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="taskkill /PID %%p" -Xmx%memory%K -jar MyApp.jar
```

Comment: I've just been writing a comment, this solves the problem! The first `%` within the OnOutOfMemoryError parameter had to be escaped with `%%`. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: No I won't! Just kidding, just have to wait some minutes before I can do that :P